# Forms not rendering from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

I am using formbuilder plugin (https://formbuilder.online/) in jquery and I am trying to create a php application that stores forms in mysql database for a user. I am not able to display the forms on back from database to the html. Form data is in JSON.

I have tried a lot of different things and I am running out of ideas. Any suggestions would be helpful. I just need the right direction to think.

PHP file (form.php)

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'abc';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'xyz';

$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT id, code FROM data";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {   
      echo $row["code"];    
 }
} else {
 echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($link);
```

Jquery File

```
$('ul li a').click(function (e) {
$.post("./form.php", function (text) {


  toggleEdit();
  var renderedForm = $('.render-wrap');

  formRenderOpts = {
    dataType: 'json',
    formData: text
  };
  console.log(text);

  renderedForm.formRender(formRenderOpts);
});
});
```

So, I am getting all the entries for JSON in console. But I am looking for single entry. For example, lets say I have 2 forms stored in database I want to display 1st form on the website. Instead I am not getting anything displayed. But I am getting all the entries in JSON format in console. I new to PHP and I think that is why I am not able to figure this out.

Comment: If the data being logged is as you expect... it's not an issue with your PHP side. Likely it's an issue with the format of the data... or the format of the html in `render-wrap`

Comment: So, I think you are right it only reads one json at time [...] but I have more than one [...], [...],... and I think that is why it is breaking and not showing any results in the front end. @smerny